# Change number before jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I can convert `arabic` number to `latin` number using this function:

```
function toEnglishDigits(str) {

    // convert arabic indic digits [٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]
    e = '٠'.charCodeAt(0);
    str = str.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, function(t) {
        return t.charCodeAt(0) - e;
    });
    return str;
}
console.log(toEnglishDigits("abc[0123456789][٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]"));
```

Now I validate my form using jQuery validation plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnConsult").click(function() {
        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.addClass("invalid-feedback");
                element.closest(".form-group").append(error);
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).addClass("is-invalid");
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).removeClass("is-invalid");
            },
        });
        $("#formConsult").validate({
            rules: {
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 10,
                },
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Now, I need to change `arabic` number before validate using jQuery validation. because `number` rule not work for `arabic` number.

how do change number from `arabic` to `latin` before validate?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the number from `Arabic` to `Latin` just before call the `validate()` method.

```
const phoneField = $('input[name="phone"]');
phoneField.val(toEnglishDigits(phoneField.val()));

$("#formConsult").validate({
  rules: {
    phone: {
       required: true,
       number: true,
       minlength: 10,
       maxlength: 10,
    },
  },
});
```